# Publish iOS App out of App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Last days, I find an iOS app that can be installed on your iPhone after follow some steps. (Principally allowing their certificate).

Here it is: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/binance-101-install-mobile-app-your-iphone-0181988/

My question is: How can I publish an app out of the App Store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for Apple Developer Enterprise Program -
 https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: By "publish" I assume you mean distributing your app to the general public?  If you only want to distribute the app within your organization, then yes, an enterprise account will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

What Binance is doing is blatantly against Apple Terms of Service and I expect their developer certificate to be revoked very soon and account to be closed. They are using their enterprise account to distribute the app to the public.